# The best way to call C++ function from shared object in python

Tags: c++, python, shared-objects

What's the best way to call C++ function from shared object in python. Can I can solve this problem without additional python extension?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could investigate [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html), although you will need to know things like the mangled name of the function and the correct calling convention.

If that doesn't work you'll need to create a C wrapper around the C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the C++ source code, I would say boost python is the best way because it's very easy to get this up and running and it's flexible. If you don't have C++ source then checkout ctypes.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use swig (http://www.swig.org/) to generate a python module wrapping the C++ code.